# Dynamically changing <div> id on new sets of photos during pagination using infinite scroll and masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-masonry

I am using Infinitescroll to set up pagination. I want to give each new set of photo to have a unique  id for the purposes of my modal. Right now, I am able to set the class (static).

`itemSelector : '.each_photo_container'`

The problem I am having is that when I try to add the div ID to the current photo's id (iterating through each photo), javascript keeps setting the ID of the new photos to the ID of the first photo from the first set.

```
$newElems.attr('id', '<%=photo[:id]%>');
```

**How do I dynamically add an ID with value photo[:id] to each new photo being loaded by infinitescroll and masonry?**

index.html.erb (I understand that the javascript has to be moved to its own file)

```
<div class="body_container">

  <div id="index_header">
     <h1>Let's look at <%=params[:search]%>:</h1>
   </div>

   <div id="photos_container">
     <% @photos_array.each do |photo| %>

         <div class='each_photo_container' id='<%=photo[:id]%>' >
           <%= link_to '#' do %>
             <%= image_tag photo[:s_url] %>
           <% end %>
         </div>

      <!-- Masonry/Pinterest Layout + InfiniteScroll/Pagination -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {

         var $container = $('#photos_container');

         $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
           $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.each_photo_container',
           });
         });


         $container.infinitescroll({
           navSelector  : 'div.#page_navigation',            
           nextSelector : 'div.#page_navigation a',    
           itemSelector : '.each_photo_container'          

         },
         //trigger masonry on infinitescroll callback and add id to div
           function(newElements){

             var $newElems = $(newElements).css({ opacity: 0 });

             $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){

               $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
               $newElems.attr('id', '<%=photo[:id]%>'); //not appending correct ID - keeps appending first element ID

               $container.masonry('appended', $newElems,true);

             });
           }

         );

       });
      </script> 

  <!-- Load Modal onClick -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
    $('#<%=photo[:id]%>').click(function (e) {

      //ajax call to fetch photo info

      var fetch_id = '<%=photo[:id]%>';
      var fetch_secret = '<%=photo[:secret]%>';  

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/photos/fetch_info',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'id' : fetch_id, 'secret' : fetch_secret },
        success: function(data){

          //edit innerHTML of basic_modal
          $('.basic_modal').html(
             //irrelevant code removed for readability
           );

          //load modal
          $('.basic_modal').modal({
            overlayClose:true
          });

        } //end success: function(result)
      });


      return false;
    });
  });
  </script>

  <% end %>

  <div class="basic_modal">
  </div>

  </div><!--End photos_container-->

  <div id="page_navigation">
  <%= link_to "Next", {:controller => "photos", :action => "index", :page => @page.to_i+1, :search => params[:search]}%>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this. Looking at Infinitescroll documentation, you can use this to refer to the current element.

`$newElems.attr('id', this.id);` fixes the problem and assigns the correct ID.